# Bug with moved questions and reputation?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, migration, daily-reputation-limit

If you get upvoted on a question, then the question gets moved over to another site - the original site deducts it from your total but does not remove it from your daily limit.

For example.

[image: bland screenshot of votes total for day]

(Picture taken whilst today button is pressed - this starts from my first bit of rep today 4/3/10)

The red line is approx at the time that [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/119251/10k-20k-tcp-connections-on-windows-servers) was moved from SuperUser.com to ServerFault.com

I have clicked the today button and checked on Jon Skeet's reputation tracker, and they both say the same thing.

I guess the reason for this is either a bug or because I can undelete my answer and get the reputation - I am not really that sure and just thought it was worth asking.

Comment: It'll probably get straightened out if you get recalculated for some reason (like asking a moderator).

Comment: @mmyers - To be honest, I don't really care to much about 30 reputation, just curious if bug or by design (and if by design - why? )

Answer (score 1):

The adjustments for the reputation cap on the source (and destination) site will happen as part of [the new reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), so you'll get back those other votes which didn't count post-cap before the delete.